# Total class mount from tables

Tags: jquery, function, variables, sum, using

Based on this

https://jsfiddle.net/tzw4mkL2/

I need to work after each table

table
total
table
total

Example: In this case, don`t work

```html
    <div class='force'>
    1
</div>
<div class='force'>
    2
</div>
<div class='force'>
    3
</div>
total:
<div id='total_forces'>
    
</div>


<div class='force'>
    1
</div>
<div class='force'>
    2
</div>
<div class='force'>
    3
</div>
total:
<div id='total_forces'>
    
</div>
```

Must inser something between them

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
var total=0;
$.each($(".force"),function(){
  total+=parseInt($(this).text());
  if(!$(this).next('div').hasClass('force')){
    $(this).next('div').text(total);
    total=0;
  }
})
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.